# Tinymce error in ie php

Tags: php

Hiiii

I am using tinymce in my website but in ie it takes an error .

```
function getHTML_TinyMCE(txtfield){

obj=document.getElementById('content_ifr');
if(obj.contentDocument){
    content=obj.contentDocument.body.innerHTML; //FireFox (getContent() messes up cursor position)
}else{
    content=tinyMCE.getContent(txtfield); //on this line error 
}
return content;
}
```

Please any one suggest

Thanks

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: object doesnot support its property or method

Comment: does the error indicate which line of the above code is throwing the error?

Comment: content=tinyMCE.getContent(txtfield);